Wi-Fi connectivity issues on Ubuntu Server
I'm trying to setup to run my old laptop as a home server using Ubuntu Server 22.04.4.
The problem is after configuration, my laptop can not detect any wifi using
nmcli device wifi list

I have tried several ways to troubleshoot:

Running nmcli device the output showed that the operating system has detected the Wi-Fi card and it is recognized as a network device.
Running
nmcli radio the output showed that WIFI was enabled.
Running rfkill the output showed that everything was unblocked.
Running lshw -c network  the output showed that I have the wireless interface driver installed
I also tried to bring up the network interface for wlan0 using ip link set wlan0 up

=> Then I decided to try using a USB Wifi Adapter and it works - it can detect and connect to the wifi. It seems that the problem might be in the built-in wifi adapter? Is there any way to fix it?
